# Android: listen to fragment shared element transitions

Tags: android, fragment, listener, transition

I have an image that is shared between two fragments. When I switch between the fragments, the corresponding views are animated. How can I listen to this transition? I want to fade another view in, as soon as the transition is over.

Comment: I guess you are looking for this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.TransitionListener.html#onTransitionEnd(android.transition.Transition)

Comment: Appears just to be working with activity transitions. I need to listen to transitions between fragments

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this inside a method ?

```
 getSharedElementEnterTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This only works if I have a transition between activities. Not between two fragments. None of the methods is called.

Comment: @AljoSt `getSharedElementEnterTransition` is a method of `Fragment` class. maybe this is not working for you because you are setting shared element transition on it's object from the fragment that initiate this sharedElement. Try `setSharedElementEnterTransition` on the called fragment then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found out you need to add the Listener during `onCreate`. it's too late if you do it during `onCreateView` and the listener will not catch anything.